# Tor browser limit download data to 657MB

Tags: configuration, onion-services, help, network-configuration

Good day

I usually download files from the Internet, and I have this 700MB rar file I really need to download. But every time I download the file on Tor browser, it mysteriously stops at 657 MB, rendering the file incomplete and useless.

How can I get over this ? Is there a hidden download space limiter in Tor browser that I don't know ?

Thank you

Comment: Nope, there's no hidden limiter.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get over this ?

Try to re-download it.

> Is there a hidden download space limiter in Tor browser that I don't know ?

No. Proof: I downloaded a 5Go ISO file without any problems.